# FeedMe Change Slug when Importing

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, plugin-feedme

I asked this question previously before Feedme was acquired by Craft, though I haven't updated Feedme & the code since now.

I'm getting the following error when processing my feeds. I'm trying to change my entries slug when they get imported but only on a certain feed - in this case - a feed with the title of 'merchants'

> Argument 1 passed to craft\feedme\Plugin::craft\feedme{closure}()
> must be an instance of craft\feedme\FeedProcessEvent, instance of
> craft\feedme\events\FeedProcessEvent given - Plugin.php: 67

The code I'm trying to run in `Plugin.php`

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    self::$plugin = $this;

    $this->_setPluginComponents();
    $this->_registerCpRoutes();
    $this->_registerTwigExtensions();
    $this->_registerVariables();

    Event::on(
      Process::class,
      Process::EVENT_STEP_BEFORE_ELEMENT_SAVE,
      function(FeedProcessEvent $event) {
        switch($event->feed['name']){
            case 'merchants':
                $element = $event->element;
                $element->slug = ElementHelper::createSlug($element->title.' '.'Coupon Codes & Promo Codes');
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What version of Feed Me and Craft are you on?

Comment: @BradBell Very latest-3.1.10

Comment: Really strange error... what if you change the function line to this: `function(craft\feedme\events\FeedProcessEvent $event) {`?

Comment: If that doesn't work, try deleting your composer.lock file, your vendor folder, and running `composer update` from your project's root to pull in a fresh set of dependencies and see if that helps.

Comment: @BradBell Changing the function seems to have quelled that fire. But now getting "Class 'craft\feedme\ElementHelper' not found - Plugin.php: 73"

Comment: Try `$element->slug = craft\helpers\ElementHelper::createSlug(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to get it working with great help from Brad Bell and Oli.

The following code changes feedme slugs on Import.

```
use craft\feedme\events\ElementEvent;
use craft\helpers\ElementHelper;
use craft\elements\Entry;
```

Adding the following Event with the namespaces above works nicely.

```
        Event::on(
          Process::class,
          Process::EVENT_STEP_BEFORE_ELEMENT_SAVE,
          function(craft\feedme\events\FeedProcessEvent $event) {
            switch($event->feed['name']){
                case 'merchants':
                    $element = $event->element;
                    $element->slug = ElementHelper::createSlug($element->title.' '.'Whatever you'd like appended!');
                    break;
            }
        });
```